# How to get the column values in list for same other column value in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I wanted get to get nested output from Sequelize findAll api.
I am retrieving rows from table and I am getting below output,

```json
[
        {
            "productId": 468,
            "ColorColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "productId": 949,
            "ColorColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "productId": 949,
            "ColorColor": "Red"
        },
        {
            "productId": 949,
            "ColorColor": "white"
        }
    ]
```

I wanted to retrieve the result as follows,

```json
[
        {
            "productId": 468,
            "ColorColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "productId": 949,
            "ColorColor": ["blue", "Red", "white"]
        }
    ]
```

Below is my models,

```
const Colors = db.sequelize.define(
    "Color",
    {
        color: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
    }
);
```

```
const PrdColors = db.sequelize.define(
    "PrdColor",
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
    },
    {
        uniqueKeys: {
            PrdColor_unique: {
                fields: ['productId', 'ColorColor']
            }
        }
    }
);

Products.hasOne(PrdColors, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
PrdColors.belongsTo(Products, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })

Colors.hasOne(PrdColors, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
PrdColors.belongsTo(Colors, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
```